# Finding out why fopen() ends prematurely?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, fopen

I have JSON file with JSON like values

```
{...} {...}...
```

I can convert it to JSON by wrapping it in `[]` and adding the comma between the curly braces, but that's not the issue.

I have about 40000 such objects in the file, that I need to import into WordPress. Now, using `wp_remote_get()` is out of the question, because the file is too large and I got errors (exhausted memory) so I used `fopen()`. I have ajax function that executes when I click import and in it, I have this code:

```
$data = fopen( 'url-to-local-file', 'r' );

while ( ! feof( $data ) ) {
    $json_line = fgets( $data );
    $json_array = json_decode( $json_line, true );

    // Import happens here
}

fclose( $data );
```

This works, kinda. After about 12000 entries I get the message that everything imports just fine. Now the number of posts that should be imported is around 3000 (there are same entries with different meta values), but I get only around 900 imported. There is no image download, just pure get the data from the array and put it in the post with `wp_insert_post()`, and some meta updating.

Is there any way that I can see why the stream stops after 6 minutes? The error log is empty. I've seen some code on line that uses `try` and `catch`, but I'm not sure where should I put it (never had to use it before).

Comment: Have you tried `set_time_limit(0);` and confirmed with your host that there isn't a max execution time of 6 minutes set for all PHP processes?

Comment: I am testing it out locally on my vagrant, where to set the time limit? On the top of the file or inside the `while` loop?

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Add

`set_time_limit(0);`

to the top of the code just after the opening PHP tag.

This will allow the script to run indefinitely and not time out.

Comment: Added it but it still imported omly 900 posts with no error